# Sentence correct

Tags: grammar, sentence

I've a video that prove(use proving but not that prove?) that I finished the writing on my own.

Which 'that' can I ellipsis, or how can I adjust my sentence into a more natural way?

Comment: **A** video that **proves**...

Comment: Or a video proving.

Answer (score 0):

First off, "I've" is a bit odd, maybe too casual.  It should more likely be "I've got" or "I have."  I've seen some rules about this but I don't remember them specifically.

Here are some acceptable options:

- I have a video that proves that I finished the writing on my own.
- I have a video proving that I finished the writing on my own.
- I have a video that proves I finished the writing on my own.
- I have a video proving I finished the writing on my own.

My sense as a speaker of US English is that people from England are more inclined to elide the second *that.*  The first sentence above strikes me as a bit wordy, so I might prefer the third, but between the second and fourth I prefer the second.  Others may disagree.

Comment: **"I've" is a bit odd, maybe too casual.** Really? I'm a well-educated adult British native speaker, and I think that _I've_ is slightly less casual than _I've got_ but not by very much. Certainly not 'odd' at all. When I was a kid in 1950s London our teachers tried to get us to drop _got_, not with much success.

Comment: Your sense that Brits elide more than speakers of AmE is certainly not true of the AmE spoken in the Philadelphia area.  We drop **that** all the time. *I know we do.*  Your final variant would be most idiomatic around here.

Comment: But I agree that "I've" meaning "I possess or own (a thing)" is somewhat rare in AmE. This sounds odd to me:  "I've a Honda".  But  "I've a sister who likes to sing and a brother who plays soccer" would be mainstream, and auxiliary "I've" as in "I've finished my homework" would also be mainstream.

Comment: @TimR - in southern England, 'I've a dog and two cats' would be slightly more 'refined' or 'posh' than saying 'I've got [those things], and would probably go with an RP accent. In other regions, e.g. the north, and Scotland and Wales, it would not stand out so much.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Setting aside the AmE/BrE differences with "got" and focusing on "I have" vs "I've"... In the Philadelphia area where I was born and bred and feel most in touch with the local AmE dialect,  if we say "I've a dog" vs "I have a dog" the former expresses more fondness for the dog than the latter.   "I've" connotes a deeper and closer relationship than "I have" does, the latter being more matter-of-fact. If we say "I have a sister" it's probably in response to a question like "Do you have any siblings?" whereas "I've a sister" would be in response to "Tell me about your family."